# Caesar Shift cipher Java program Solution needed:

Tags: java

This is the question that my CompSci teacher gave me, how do I exactly do the shift with only loops, no arrays? Question is below:

The Caesar Cypher takes a String and coverts every letter to a letter a certain amount of letters over(called a shift), without messing with spaces,digits, or punctuations. For example: If a cypher had a shift of -2, then the cypher would do the following.

Ex: Is it safe? Good

Result: Gq gr qxdc? Emmb

To easily understand the cypher, you can look at the following:

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

xyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx

The first row is the original code, the second row is the encrypted code.

Write a program that will receive a sentence and the amount of the shift. Then print out the encrypted code, make sure you avoid any punctuations, spaces, and digits.

I appreciate all help!!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any arrays, do it directly on the string.
A string is just an array of characters. Of course a string is some kind of array too, but this was probably his idea.